# is it possible a htm file in jsf2?

Tags: jsf, file-upload, jsf-2

I'm using JSF, I tried using file uploader but a html file isn't supported.

my error is:

> org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

You maybe missing **`enctype="multipart/form-data"`**

```
 <form action="..." enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
   <p>
   What is your name? <input type="text" name="submit-name"><br>
   What files are you sending? <input type="file" name="files"><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Send"> <input type="reset">
 </form>
```

Reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2